# Too much taxes?

Tags: lateral-thinking

Jack is a law-abiding US citizen who was filing his first taxes at age 21. He put his information into a free online e-filer and got the shock of his life. Jack only had \$3000 in income - but the return said that he owed \$2800 in taxes! How was this possible?

Comment: Did his parents file any taxes on his behalf before him?

Comment: I have some ideas... but I would like to see how wacky our country can be from the creative thinkers here.

Comment: well, given that the question is now closed, what was the answer you were thinking of?

Answer (score 4):

The first answer that comes to my mind is that Jack is a storekeeper who owes sales taxes. Even though his net income after deductions is only \$3,000, his gross sales could be around \$40,000, which had \$2,800 (7%) of unremitted sales taxes collected on it, and out of which \$37,000 was deducted as cost of goods sold and other business expenses.

Comment: (assuming that this is in a state with 7% income tax. Figures might be different.)

Comment: He did say "how is this possible," not give me an absolute perfect explanation.